# how to perform background jobs in azure

Tags: azure

I am new to azure.
I want to run some background process on schedule interval in azure.
for example i have sample web app that send test mail.how can I runthat on every 10 minutes in azure.

i read about webjobs and how can i schedule them. I tried also creating aconsole app and uploading .exe. it runs but gets filed.

I dont know how i can upload web app also as web job same as I did for exe??

or need to opt for another option like worker role..

I m totally new  to it.. so please guys suggest what would be suitable for my requirement.

I will go through it .

**EDIT:**

Sending mail is not my requirement. i m just doing that to check is my web job running succesfully at scheduled time interval or not.

but as i m getting unexpected response i think i should write some other code like write textfile azure storage account at every minute..

as i m totaly new.. dont have any idea about that ..anyone can share me any good link or sample demo if you can.please.

Comment: You could use a [scheduled azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to develop a web job.

**First**

Upload a zip file that contains your executable or script file as well as any supporting files needed to run the program or script. The supported executable or script file types are listed as below.

[image]

For example, if you want to use a console application as the web job, we can go to the [ApplicationSolutionFolder/bin] and compress the Release or Debug folder as an zip file(It's better to use Release folder), then upload this zip file to azure as the web job.

**Second:**

We can develop it via Visual Studio: [Deploy a WebJobs project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#deploy)

**Update:**

As you want to run every 10 minutes, we can set the triggers as scheduled and set the CRON expressions as [0 */10 * * * *] when we upload our zip file.

[image]

More information about CRON expressions, we can refer to: [CRON expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions)

Comment: so u want ot say i need to code my function like send mail in console application? and then when i will add it as web job and schedule its run at eevry min supose.than?

Comment: than wht willl hapen? exe will get execute? evry min? and i will recieve mail?

Comment: thanks @Lee Liu for your time.. but ihave tried doing this way.as well as from scheduler job collection.

what hapen in first case. id dont get mail that time when webjob runs succes.like it run already  for 40 times and i got only 6 mails.that also having different time interval

Comment: in secod case where i scheduled my web job from scheduler job collection.. it keeps runnig scussfully every 1 minutes( i set 1 as of now).. but i get only one 1st mail

Comment: so m not able to getting what is happening.. so is this right approach?

Comment: please check my edit..if u can help me out with that

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati You can check the log of the web job to see if the web job worked fine. Find your web job in portal and right click, you will see the log button.

Comment: yes i did it. i saved textfile at evry minute in azure storage account..and it working fine. although log of mail sending was also succesfull.but i want not getting mail properly..there might b some time conflicts..but this file saving working fine..so it seems my web job will work good

Comment: Thank you for your time and affords.. i really appreciate  it.